# Pass PHP values into mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have recently started using mPDF and have been able to create a PDF using the HTML tags it offers to you. However, if, for example, you wanted to create an invoice and needed to pass through an attribute to fill in relevant fields like gross weekly expense etc is that possible? So for example:

```
$foo = bar; $html = '

Lorum Ipsem <.?php echo '$foo';></php>

Donec mauris....

';
```

I'm aware there is probably a simple explanation for this but because of the lack of documentation in general for this problem I'm struggling to resolve it. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = '

Lorum Ipsem ' . $foo . '

Donec mauris....

';
```

OR

```
$html = "

Lorum Ipsem $foo

Donec mauris....

";
```

PHP [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) are concatenated with `.`'s or you can parse variable values directly in Strings if you use double-quotes. See the linked documentation for more information.

Comment: That is perfect thank you. And also for the extra information, I am now reading through it and it is incredibly useful! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  The documentation is always your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = '

Lorum Ipsem '.$foo.'

Donec mauris....';
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP why you have done this in order to help them understand the usage.